How to run scons tests in a customized environment?
I'm using windows 2022, where Visual Studio and Windows SDK are in a customized location.
I download the scons 4.0.0 source from github and then build scons. All works fine.
Then I modify some code in scons and would like to verify if scons works fine after that.
I'm doing this by running scons tests by issuing python runtest.py -a
As expected, a lot of test cases fail due to "'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command", which should be caused by the fact that scons fails to figure out the cl/link/etc. as they are in an abnormal place on my windows.
I go through scons docs and try fixing failed test cases by updating the SConstruct content in test file. For example, for test\AR\AR.py:
Originally it was:
    test.write('SConstruct', """
    foo = Environment(LIBS = ['foo'], LIBPATH = ['.'])
    ar = foo.Dictionary('AR')
    bar = Environment(LIBS = ['bar'], LIBPATH = ['.'], AR = r'%(_python_)s wrapper.py ' + ar)
    foo.Library(target = 'foo', source = 'foo.c')
    bar.Library(target = 'bar', source = 'bar.c')
    
    obj = foo.Object('main', 'main.c')
    
    foo.Program(target = 'f', source = obj)
    bar.Program(target = 'b', source = obj)
    """ % locals())

I changed that to:
    test.write('SConstruct', """
    foo = Environment(LIBS = ['foo'], LIBPATH = ['.'] + <my customized lib path>, CPPPATH = <my cusomized include path>, ENV = {'PATH': <my PATH env>})
    ar = foo.Dictionary('AR')
    bar = Environment(LIBS = ['bar'], LIBPATH = ['.'] + <my customized lib path>, CPPPATH = <my cusomized include path>, AR = r'%(_python_)s wrapper.py ' + ar, ENV = {'PATH' : <my PATH env>})
    foo.Library(target = 'foo', source = 'foo.c')
    bar.Library(target = 'bar', source = 'bar.c')
    
    obj = foo.Object('main', 'main.c')

    foo.Program(target = 'f', source = obj)
    bar.Program(target = 'b', source = obj)
    """ % locals())`

By doing so, test\AR\AR.py can successfully pass!
However, it is really hard for me to look into every failed test cases, update the Environment function variables in their SConstruct file...
So I wonder if there is any more efficient way for me to go.
Thank you in advance.

Curious why you're working on SCons 4.0.0 when 4.8.0 is the current version? Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed? Which version of Python? Which code in SCons are you changing? Can you post a diff of your changes? Also did you know SCons has a discord server, user mailing list and github with discussions?

SCons 4.3 was the first version that supported Visual Studio 2022 so you're not really going to have luck using 4.0. It's not just paths - there's a whole bunch of stuff that has to be entered in internal lookup tables, etc. to get a new MSVC version going.
SCons for recent versions relies on vswhere to report where the necessary build tools can be found. Assuming vshwere can find your non-standard location, it should just work. If not, there are variables like MSVC_USE_SETTINGS and MSVC_USE_SCRIPT that can help getting things right.
There should be no need at all to modify the tests.
